# How to create crash dump file for Java application in Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, dump

I have a java based application running on windows 10 machine. Some times it's crashed without having any logs. I need to create crash dump file when it's crashed.

I already tried to create registry under WER as shown in following figure and tried to create crash dump file.But I was unable to find crash dump file in particular directory which was configured in the registry, configured here.
[image]

Comment: See a basic tutorial "how to create dumps in java"  first: https://www.baeldung.com/java-heap-dump-capture. If you read it, come back if you have any questions. For now I vote to close this question.

Comment: Hi @krokodilko. thanks for your reply. But It's about collecting heap dumps. Is it same to the crash dump documents?
What are we going to collect using above registry?

Comment: Try procdump or DebugDiag tools.